# How to write to ORC files using BucketingSink in Apache Flink?

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink, orc

I'm working on a Flink streaming program that reads kafka messages and dump the messages to ORC files on AWS s3. I found there is no document about the integration of Flink's BucketingSink and ORC file writer. and there is no such an ORC file writer implementation can be used in BucketingSink.

I'm stuck here, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, a `BucketingSink` writer for ORC files would be a great feature. However, it hasn't been contributed to Flink yet. You would have to implement such a writer yourself.

I'm sure the Flink community would help designing and reviewing the writer, if you would consider contributing it to Flink.

Comment: thanks Fabian. I have checking `StreamWriterBase`, and I want to extend this class. The [ORC writer](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/java/core/src/java/org/apache/orc/Writer.java) does not accept a stream. So I have to implement the `Writer` interface. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail, but it should be possible to implement the `Writer` interface instead of the `StreamWriterBase` interface. The writer would wrap ORC's [core-java Writer](https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html).

Comment: @Freedom have you made any progress on Writing ORC files using BucketingSink ? If yes, will you be able to share the code ? Thanks

Comment: In the current form (Flink 1.5.0), the BucketingSink Writer is not very suitable to write ORC files. The community is working on improving the interface to better support batch-based writers such as ORC and Parquet.

Comment: I spent some time trying to develop a ORCWriter for BucketingSink by implementing org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.Writer but had very little success. 

The tricky part is how to implement the flush() and getPos() methods. These two methods require access to the output stream, which is hidden in ORC's writer. In addition, ORC seems to use one independent stream writing one field, and end up with several co-existent output streams, which make flush() and getPos() promiscuous.

I am looking forward to the new API that @FabianHueske mentioned.

Comment: The [StreamingFileSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html) was added a while back and supports bulk-encoded writers. Right now, it supports Parquet, but an ORC writer should be possible too.